# Problema en condicion consulta SQL MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas compañeros tengo un problema con una consulta SQL en MYSQL, les explico como son las tablas, Tengo una tabla de **Eventos** que basicamente son cumpleaños, tienen entre otras cosas una hora de inicio y una de fin, luego tengo otra tabla de **Materiales** que basicamente serian elementos como Cama Elastica,Castillo inflable, etc. Estas tablas tienen una relacion N a N lo cual me genera una **tabla intermedia** con ambas claves, En mi consulta lo que tengo que resolver es que me muestre entre 2 horarios diferentes los materiales que estan disponibles en esos horarios, es decir que no estan ocupados por los eventos.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT nombre FROM Material WHERE id
            NOT IN
                (SELECT idMaterial FROM EventoMaterial WHERE idEvento
                         IN
                            (SELECT id FROM Evento WHERE fecha = '".$fecha."' AND horaInicio >= '".$inicio."' AND horaFin <= '".$fin."'))
```

El problema aqui es que por ejemplo si tengo un evento que comienza 19:30 y termina 21:30 y por ejemplo tiene asignado una Cama Elastica y un Castillo, y yo como consulta pido que me muestre los materiales disponibles entre 19:30 y 21:00 me va a mostrar esa Cama Elastica y ese Castillo mas haya de que esten ocupados en esa "Franja horaria" por llamarlo de alguna manera, por que no se cumple la condicion de fin. No encuentro una forma de que por decir de alguna manera me tome la condicion de inicio pero la de fin se adecue o algo asi al evento. E intentado de todo y no encuentro solucion.

Espero me puedan ayudar muchisimas gracias

Comment: Primero, considero que tus consultas deberían ser re-escritas usando simplemente `JOIN`, en vez de usar `NOT IN` y de usar sub-consultas. Segundo, lo que dices aquí: *No encuentro una forma de que por decir de alguna manera me tome la condicion de inicio pero la de fin se adecue o algo asi al evento*  suena a algo ilógico, a un problema quizá ficticio que se crea debido a un error de enfoque en tu programa. Si algo está ocupado hasta la 21:30 no te puede aparecer libre a las 21:00, porque se libera media hora después. ¿Podrías explicar con más claridad qué es lo que quieres, con un ejemplo?

Comment: Es tan simple como lo que he explicado, si yo consulto entre dos horarios 19:30 y 21:30 y el evento en realidad termina 22:00 no me lo va a tomar por el simple hecho de la consulta que dice que si el horario de finalización del evento es menor o igual al introducido por el usuario. Cómo mi horario es media hora menor al del evento entonces no me lo toma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo el problema que planteas. Pero solo cuestión de aclarar un pequeño detalle adicional, voy a modificar tu ejemplo un poco...

Digamos que buscas mostrar los materiales disponibles entre `19:30` y `20:00`. Y digamos que ya se ocupa la cama elástica para un evento de `20:00` a `21:00`. En este caso, asumo que la cama debe considerarse disponible. Me parece razonable que no se considere que haya un conflicto de horario al minuto preciso de las `20:00`.

Tomando esto en cuenta, y el ejemplo que planteastes en tu pregunta, la parte clave que debes corregir es tu condicion con las horas (Cambié la notación de tus variables para legibilidad):

```
AND horaInicio >= @inicio
AND horaFin <= @fin
```

...que debes cambiar a:

```
AND horaFin > @inicio
AND horaInicio < @fin
```

Aprovechando para simplificar la consulta, quedaría así:

```
select nombre
  from material
 where id not in (
   select em.idMaterial
     from Evento e
     join EventoMaterial em
       on em.idEvento = e.id
    where e.fecha = @fecha
      and e.horaFin > @inicio
      and e.horaInicio < @fin
 )
```

---

Nota adicional: Aunque la pregunta tiene que ver con el SQL, pero ya que se puede ver que estás usando variables de PHP, o algo así, que concatenas directamente a tu cadena SQL, aprovecho para advertirte que no es buena práctica hacer esto. Lo correcto es parametrizar las consultas en vez de concatenar los valores directamente en la cadena SQL. Haciendo esto te protejes de la inyección SQL y de varios otros problemas.

Comment: Por favor comenta aquí si necesitas dejarme un comentario respecto a la respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: Wow lo acabo de probar, ayer no pude por que estaba fuera de mi casa, funciona perfecto estoy intentando entender esta logica
      e.horaFin > $inicio
      and e.horaInicio < $fin
Pero no consigo entenderla del todo, (estoy aprendiendo). Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda y si me puedes aclarar lo de arriba te agradeceria muchisimo, muchas gracias por todo

Comment: Si quieres profundizar más en cuanto a la teoría de cómo comprobar si 2 rangos de fechas se traslapan, puedes leer [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/q/325933/4955425), pero está en inglés.

Comment: @Gaston si te funciona esta respuesta, por favor, márcala como aceptada pulsando en el ✓ que hay en la parte superior izquierda de la respuesta.